# Size of 2 D array

Tags: c, sizeof

```
int array[][2] = {
{1,0}, 
{2,2},
{3,4},
{4,17}
};

int main()
{
    /* calculate array size */

    printf(" => number of positions to capture : %d", (int)(sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])));
    func(array);
    return 0;
}
void func(int actu[][2])
{
    /* calculate array size */
    printf(" => number of positions to capture : %d", (int)(sizeof(actu)/sizeof(actu[0])));
 }
```

Result:

```
 => number of positions to capture : 4 -- inside main
 => number of positions to capture : 0 -- inside func -- I believe I should get 4 here too
```

Size of a same arrray in calling and called function are giving different values. Please, help me to find the issue.

Comment: On of them is taking the size of the array, the other is taking the size of a pointer decayed from an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because when arrays are passed as function argument, they are converted to a pointer to the first element.

So in `main`, `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` gives the array's length `4`, as you may expect.

In `func`, `sizeof(actu)` is the size of a pointer, typically 4 bytes in 32-bit machine or 8 bytes in 64-bit machine, while `sizeof(actu[0]` is still two `int`, which is `8` if `int` is 4 bytes. In your machine, the pointer is 4 bytes, so integer division `4/8` outputs `0`.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1461449/2718447) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37545/2718447) (note the first link is talking about C++, not C, so while the mechanism is the same, in C there are no such thing as references (`&`)). The array has decayed into a pointer, so `sizeof(actu)` is not equal to `sizeof(array)`.

Comment: Here too... second answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c